# Multiple if, then for hostnames

Tags: bash

Tried looking this up, but don't know what I'm looking for.

I have 4 servers that are keyed to a license file, so the hostnames have to match. I have 4 license files, and I am running this through Opsworks, so hands off installs. I have an if in a bash that appears to be kicking off an unexpected end of file.

```
if [ "$HOSTNAME" = devprint01 ]; then
    cp /home/user/installs/config/linux.cfg.01 /var//filters/linux.cfg
if [ "$HOSTNAME" = devoprint01 ]; then
    cp /home/user/installs/config/linux.cfg.d01 /var//filters/linux.cfg
if [ "$HOSTNAME" = devoprint02 ]; then
    cp /home/user/installs/config/linux.cfg.d02 /var//filters/linux.cfg
if [ "$HOSTNAME" = priprint01 ]; then
    cp /home/user/installs/config/linux.cfg.p01 /var//filters/linux.cfg
if [ "$HOSTNAME" = priprint02 ]; then
    cp /home/user/installs/config/linux.cfg.p02 /var//filters/linux.cfg
fi
```

There is a bunch of cp and other commands in front of this that are working fine, so it has to be something I am missing on this.  Should there be something in between each if statement, or should I fi between each one?

Comment: `elif` is your friend, though I'd also consider a `case` statement for this purpose instead of messing with chained `if` clauses at all. BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ is a useful resource for syntax questions.

Comment: ie. `case $HOSTNAME in devprint01) suffix=01;; devoprint01) suffix=d01;; devoprint02) suffix=d02; priprint01) suffix=p01;; priprint02) suffix=p02;; esac; [[ $suffix ]] && cp "/path/to/linux.cfg.$suffix" /var/filters/linux.cfg`

Comment: Frankly, it probably makes more sense to just have an associative array and not deal with flow control at all.

Comment: `declare -A extensions=( [devprint01]=01 [devoprint01]=d01 [devoprint02]=d02 [priprint01]=p01 [priprint02]=p02 )`, and then you can refer to `"${extensions[$HOSTNAME]}"` to get the right extension for your current host.

Comment: ...so, something in the above will probably be helpful to you -- but I'm not convinced that this is a good StackOverflow question as it is. It doesn't meet our criteria for containing a [mcve] -- for example, there's no specific error message included in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `fi` for the first four ifs.

If your bash is recent enough (4.0+), you can use an associative array instead:

```
declare -A suffix=([devprint01]=01
                   [devoprint01]=d01
                   [devoprint02]=d02
                   [priprint01]=p01
                   [priprint02]=p02
)

cp /home/user/installs/config/linux.cfg.${suffix[$HOSTNAME]} /var/filters/linux.cfg
```

Comment: An `elif` between them makes more sense than a `fi` for each, since they can't all be true. Though a single `case` statement makes more sense than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can always consider a function. Using a function makes it easier to use the code on different places (an array will help to).

When there is some algorithm, you can use code for the translation. That way you can also see possible mistakes or add hosts later:

```
getcfg() {
   echo "$1" | sed -r 's/devprint//;s/(d|p).*print/\1/'
}

/home/user/installs/config/linux.cfg.$(getcfg ${HOSTNAME}) /var/filters/linux.cfg

# Or test it with
for testhostname in devprint01 devoprint01 devoprint02 priprint01 priprint02; do
   echo "${testhostname} => $(getcfg ${testhostname}) "
done
```